# Error loading "SpriteFont1". File not found

Tags: xna, xna-content-pipeline, spritefont

I have an issue while trying to load a font file with the extension ".xnb" and I am receiving following error:

```
Error loading "SpriteFont1". File not found.
```

For following code:

```
public static Dictionary<string, T> LoadListContent<T>(this ContentManager contentManager, string contentFolder)
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(contentManager.RootDirectory + "/" + contentFolder);
            if (!dir.Exists)
                throw new DirectoryNotFoundException();
            Dictionary<String, T> result = new Dictionary<String, T>();

            FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.*");
            foreach (FileInfo file in files)
            {
                string key = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);


                result[key] = contentManager.Load<T>(key);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

The file is actually there and I am getting here `FileInfo[] files = dir.GetFiles("*.*");` one file which is present in the folder.

I am using the function like this:

```
fontList = ContentLoader.LoadListContent<SpriteFont>(Content, "Fonts");
```

Is there something which I have overlooked?

Comment: using a breakpoint, what is the value of `key`?

Comment: If it is `"SpriteFont1.xnb"` you may need to strip the extension? I forget how XNA content pipeline works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reflecting the ContentManager.Load(assetName) method, it gives this note:

assetName:

Asset name, **relative to the loader root directory**, and not including the .xnb extension.

---

Even though `files` has the needed copy of "SpriteFont1" in it, the ContentManager isn't looking for the file in `files`. It's looking for "SpriteFont1" in the ContentManager's root directory `/Content` . Try changing the ContentManager's root directory to `/Content/contentFolder`.

```
Content.RootDirectory = "Content/contentFolder";//amend the line in the Game1 constructor
```

or change `key` to:

```
string key = "/contentFolder/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name);
```